# Hard drive fan making a rhythmic high pitched noise? (Late 2006 17" iMac)

Tags: hard-drive, imac

identifier - `iMac5,1`
I've had this issue going on for a bit and I've gotten used to it, but I'm really wondering what it is.
So, the hard drive fan in my iMac makes this constant high pitched noise and it corresponds with the speed of the fan. If the fan speed gets higher, the noise gets higher pitched and is faster, and vice versa.
(Please comment with whatever else you need me to include about the problem, not too sure what to include.)

Comment: either something stuck in it, or just simply to old and needs new bearing (or new fan). you can try to vacuum it.

Comment: How often do you clean the fan?

Comment: @ScottPorter Never did, I'm a bit hesitant to crack open the computer.

Comment: @viktorahlström It is good preventative maintenance.